# Connect to oracle database after switch user from root to oracle Using Unix shell script

Tags: unix

The below code is working properly in unix server1 but showing error in diff unix server2.(both server has same config).If i will add 2 export commands again after `'su - oracle'` its working in unix server2.  I need to write a generic code to work both the server.any config need to change in unix server2 ?

> ERROR IN unix server2:-ksh[6]: WHENEVER: not found [No such file or directory]

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 TMP_ORA_HOME=`grep 'ORACLE_HOME=' /home/oracle/.bash_profile |awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
 export ORACLE_HOME=$TMP_ORA_HOME
 export ORACLE_SID=ABCD
 OUTPUT=`su - oracle <<EOF
 ORAENV_ASK=NO
 . $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oraenv
 sqlplus -s '/as sysdba'
 WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
 SELECT 1 from dual;
 EOF` 
 echo  $OUTPUT 
 exit 0
```

Comment: Check your script here. https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Check config file(`.bashrc` | `.profile`) for your user `oracle`. You might be setting `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` in server1 but missing in server2

Comment: 1. Make sure that /home/oracle/.bash_profile are the same, and 2. add a line in the above script to echo ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME just before sourcing $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oraenv (line 6)